# Высота блока равная ширине android

Tags: java, android

Имеется LinearLayout с ориентацией horizontal в нем 3 элемента CardView с одинаковым весом (в строке получается 3 элемента CardView одинаковой ширины) , каким образом я могу сделать чтоб CardView был квадратным , т.е высота равнялась ширине?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvHistoryItem1"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivHistoryItem1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvHistoryItem2"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivHistoryItem2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvHistoryItem3"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivHistoryItem3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант, сделать кастомный вью, наследник `CardView` и переопределить у него метод `onMeasure` таким образом:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Программно получаете ширину и высоту, далее высоте присваиваем значение ширины, либо жестко фиксируем размер.